# ListView, mark the position where the user touches

Tags: android

I have a custom `listview` with a `setOnTouchListener`

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f47920"));
                  break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                  break; 

            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

And I ran into a strange problem: When the user holds over one item and drag the finger to an next item in the listview, the previous item will keep the color, as the application thinks that I try to select several items from the list. So how can I remove the color if the user holds down a finger and drags up and down on the list?

Hope you guys understood what I try to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the view in your case? Is it an individual list item or main listview ?
If it is a listview, then try to handle the case

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : 
//Check position here, if it is out of your view, then change the color back.
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case you need either ACTION_UP or ACTION_DOWN event not ACTION_MOVE so to avoid ACTION_MOVE you can do something like this:

```
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         isDown = false;            
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !isDown)
    {
        // action you want to perform
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        isDown = true;
    }
```

as far as changing color is concerned, you can store previous view in a global variable and while going for next touch, you can change that global view color to normal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to highlight ListView item on click/touch than it's better to use selectors instead of overiding OnTouchListener().

If you want to set the color, you need a StateListDrawable. You can set this on your list using the android:listSelector attribute, defining the drawable in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_disabled" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" />
</selector>
```

Or you can use the same selector for item of the ListView.