# onTouchEvent() of Activity fires 3 times?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, touch-event

In my TitleScreen activity, I have...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   Log.d("MyActivity", "in onTouchEvent!");

   MediaPlayer myplayer = MediaPlayer.create(TitleScreen.this, R.raw.mysound);
   myplayer.start();
   startActivity(new Intent("com.example.GAME"));
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

This was causing the sound to play 3 times in rapid succession upon tapping the screen, making the sound I wanted to play have a delayed echo.  I checked the logs, and my "in onTouchEvent!" message was logged 3 times.

This activity is just a static image for a title screen, and the idea is you tap it to start the next activity, and when you do so, the specified sound should player.

For my particular issue, I was able to solve it by placing a global level int variable:

```
private static int playerInstances = 0;
```

and then wrapping my MediaPlayer lines with:

```
if (playerInstances == 0)
{
    MediaPlayer myplayer = MediaPlayer.create(TitleScreen.this, R.raw.critical1);
    myplayer.start();
    playerInstances++;
}
```

This insured that that code only executed once.  So my problem is solved.  I'm just wondering why I was getting onTouchEvent three times in one tap.

Comment: I think its because all three touch events (ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE)getting called. Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777459/listview-mark-the-position-where-the-user-touches/11777780#11777780

Comment: Hah, brilliant!  You should put that as the answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Hmmm... happy it helped... you could have up voted for that ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you can actually do on your `onTouchEvent` (better than using the static variable) is:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   final int action = event.getAction();

   if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       Log.d("MyActivity", "in onTouchEvent!");
       MediaPlayer myPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(TitleScreen.this, R.raw.mysound);
       myPlayer.start();
       startActivity(new Intent("com.example.GAME"));
   }
   return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the onTouchevent() has three events that are called once you touch the screen i.e. ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP. So if you do not apply the condition for these events separately , then 3 calls will be made to the code in the onTouchEvent() .So make sure to write the code in appropriate action event.