# Null Pointer Exception, Webview on touch event

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, touch-event

People started having problem with my app lately. Force closes while they are scrolling pages in webview. Below is the stack trace that they sent me. **Please note that the null pointer exception is occurring in the system-provided WebView code**. Anyone have an idea what might be wrong? If needed I'll attach the code of any parts of my app which could be relevant to the failure in the WebView code.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException  at
 android.webkit.WebView.onTouchEvent(WebView.java:5351)  at
 android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3952)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:995)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)  at
 android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1034)  at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1711) at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1145)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)  at
 com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2217)  at
 android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1901)  at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)  at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)  at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)  at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for any tips.

Edit:

I disable the touch listener when the page is loading and enable it on page finished.

```
webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "DragonLords");
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(1);
        webView.loadData("<body style='background-color: black'>&nbsp</body>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
        webView.setOnTouchListener(this.disablingTouchListener);


private final OnTouchListener disablingTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return webviewDisabled;
        }
    };
```

Comment: please attach ur webview onTouchEvent code

Comment: Added the code in the question.

Comment: I don't c anything which can cause NullPointerException in OnTouchListener. Well, 1 thing I doubt is touch event is taking all the 3 i.e ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP and ACTION_MOVE. I am not sure but may b its causing problem. Have a look at this link to enable only 1 touch event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777459/listview-mark-the-position-where-the-user-touches/11777780#11777780

Comment: What version of the OS was this issue detected on? There are significant changes between Gingerbread, ICS and JB version of WebView so without knowing the version of OS it is impossible to see what might be causing the issue? (asked by user @vino)

Comment: @Braj - the code in which the null pointer exception occurs **is not written by the poster**.  Instead it is **shipped with the Android installation**.

Comment: @keag - please note that this is an old and likely abandoned question.  By editing it for format, you moved it back to the top of the display list, and caused further work to be done on it.  Please think twice about making trivial edits to old questions which may no longer be of importance unless someone with a similar problem searches for them.

Comment: @Chris It was at the top of unanswered, I didn't even check the timestamp.